# How can I construct this tree?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

Hey guys I'm getting a bit lost when trying to draw a BST with these keys  50 30 70 20 40 60 80 15 25 35 45 36,  they are inserted in this order, How exactly this tree looks like?

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. Creating binary search trees are trivial, I suggest you use Google (or your class notes) to figure this out because this is an extremely well-documented problem.

Comment: Tthis links may be help you. [code](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/binary_search_tree.htm)   [slide for learn basics](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiG_v6j6f3VAhWDsxQKHfaJDF4QFgg5MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.txstate.edu%2F~rp44%2Fcs3358_092%2FLectures%2Fbst.ppt&usg=AFQjCNFrnJ7j5ieBuZ4AhxH8PjMbEqQYTg)

Comment: You must show your codes, trying and possible error or misbehavior to ask others help in Stack Overflow. don't worry about down-votes. they voted down because you  ask a unclear question. Read [MCVE] to see how to ask question in SO

Answer (score 1):

Since you start with 50, it is the root, so this is the result:

[image: Binary Search Tree]